# Improving testability of ASP.NET site without rewriting to MVC or WCSF

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web app which is growing.

It is done in traditional web forms. While I would like to convert it WCSF to improve testability, this is time-prohibitive. I have taken the action to only make method calls in ASPX code behind which call the appropriate methods in the classes in App_Code so the spaghetti code is gone, which is good.

What else could I do to improve testability without any fundamental rewrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Web Site project? I find Web Applications are more structured and easier to maintain. I'm not sure if they are more testable. Then do use namespaces where a web site does not.

Have you considered using a UI pattern such as MVP? You also might get partial coverage with creating interfaces for your code-behinds and testing against the interface. Watch out for hidden side-effects (changing the state of a dropdown within a method, it hidden behavior).

A book I found helpful was '[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)' by Michael Feathers.

Comment: In general - kind a disliked your answer. But reference is really good. :)

Comment: I don't know there is much you can do to *really* test web forms. It's like asking someone to pull teeth without Novocaine.

Comment: Completely different with your comment. Could upvote it ad infinitum.

Comment: Good idea with the book. It is a website project, yes. However, the big problem is that the ASP.NET internals themselves are where testability falls down. As stated, I'm not keen on a rewrite so stated I didn't want to go the MVC route.